# I need to fetch html tags given inside textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I had to fetch html elements and its attributes that is given inside textbox. How can i fetch it using jquery.My code is...

```
    $("#textbox_id").html().filter('img').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
```

In my above code i like to get id of all img tags inside textbox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Final Solution...**

```
$("#textbox_id").html('html content given here');   

$("#textbox_id").find('img').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Textboxes don't have html inside them, they only have a value, which you can access via .val(). Then you pass that string to jQuery:

```
var textboxHTML = $("#textbox_id").val();
$(textboxHTML).filter("img").each(function () {
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```